# How to set the title when playing music with remove control on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, background-music

I'm working on a radio app, which supports playing music in background. But i get stuck in how to set the title of music to remove control.

The difference between my app and "Music" is as following:
[image: Difference]

What i should do to make my app display the title of a music like "Music" do?

Thanks!

Comment: are you try to add label and all this thing on one view?

Comment: i just want to add a label to display music name

Comment: So all that images are button? and add in view right?

Comment: Double tap home button, and right swipe the multitask bar will show this. This view wasn't created by me, it was created by iOS. I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Sorry I am not understand and if this all view is inbuild then i think you try to add label on that view  but still i am not using this

Comment: Thanks for reply, and I redescribed this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478383/how-to-set-the-title-when-playing-music-in-background-on-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the text of the now playing label by calling the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, this will also allow you to modify the song name, album, artist, and album artwork on the lock screen.

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaItem.h>

MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt;


- (void)changeTrackTitles
{
  Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

    if (playingInfoCenter) 
    {
        albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"HexagonArtwork"]];
        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [songInfo setObject:@"SongName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:@"AlbumName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:@"ArtistName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
    }
}
```

Code from: [jaysonlane.net](http://jaysonlane.net/tech-blog/2012/04/lock-screen-now-playing-with-mpnowplayinginfocenter/)

Answer (score 6):

Here's the example code:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaItem.h>

MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt;


- (void)changeTrackTitles
{
  Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

    if (playingInfoCenter) 
    {
        albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"HexagonArtwork"]];
        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [songInfo setObject:@"SongName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:@"AlbumName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:@"ArtistName" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well on iOS5, but doesn't support iOS4. How could this be done on iOS4? Thanks a ton!