# How to set the title when playing music in background on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, audio, background, background-music

I'm working on a radio app, which supports playing music in background. But i get stuck in how to set the title of music to remove control.

In remote control, my app looks like this(RadioTaste is my app's name):

[image]
[image]

And Apple's "Music" app looks like this:

[image]
[image]

What I should do to make my app display the title of a music like the "Music" app does?